# Difficulty Running Bayesian Gamma Regression with PyMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, gamma-distribution

PyMC3 has excellent functionality for dealing with Bayesian regressions, so I've been trying to leverage that to run a Bayesian Gamma Regression using PyMC3 where the likelihood would be Gamma.

From what I understand, running any sort of Bayesian Regression in PyMC3 requires the `pymc3.glm.GLM()` function, which takes in a model formula in Patsy form (e.g. y ~ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_m), the dataframe, and a distribution.

However, ***the issue is that the `pymc3.glm.GLM()` function requires a `pymc3..families` object*** (https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/glm/families.py) for the distribution. But ***the Gamma distribution doesn't show up as one of the families*** built into the package so I'm stuck. Or is the Gamma function family hidden somewhere? Would appreciate any help in this matter!

---

**For context:**
I have a dataframe of features `[x_1, x_2, ..., x_m]` (call it `X`) and a target variable (call it `y`). This is the code I have prepared so far, but just need to figure out how to get the Gamma distribution in as my likelihood.

```
import pymc3 as pm

# Combine X and y into a single dataframe
patsy_DF = X
patsy_DF['y'] = y

# Get Patsy Formula 
all_columns = "+".join(X.columns)
patsy_formula = "y~" + all_columns

# Instantiate model
model = pm.Model()

# Construct Model
with model:
    # Fit Bayesian Gamma Regression
    pm.glm.GLM(patsy_formula, df_dummied, family=pm.families.Gamma())
        # !!! ... but pm.families.Gamma() doesn't exist ... !!!

    # Get MAP Estimate and Trace
    map_estimate = pm.find_MAP(model=model)
    trace = pm.sample(draws=2000, chains=3, start = map_estimate)

# Get regression results summary (coefficient estimates, 
pm.summary(trace).round(3)
```

Comment: Correct, the `GLM` function doesn't have implemented support for gamma distribution.  You'll have to explicitly write out the gamma regression model.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that R has better support for these types of models. For example, the `rstanarm` package has [an example of Bayesian Gamma Regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/continuous.html#gamma-regression-example). Personally, I use PyMC3 or Stan when I need the flexibility of arbitrarily complex hierarchical models, but tend to defer back to R when doing more standard regression analyses.